# elements padding adjust when the size (width/height) of header adjusts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, animate.css

So I'm working on my website, and I sill can't get a grasp of JavaScrip or how to really work with it.

I have a header that when shrinks (height wise), my aside menu's padding (padding-top that is) will adjust with.

When the user reaches the end of my webpage, the height of the header will adjust back, and so will my aside's padding-top with it.

So I'd like for my aside to move up and down, along with my header when it shrinks up and down in height.

This is what I have so far...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var hh = $('header').height();

$('aside').css('padding-top', hh)

});
```

Comment: If possible prepare jsfiddle for it

Answer (score 0):

Without testing, this is what I thought of. It might work or at least nudge you in the right direction at least!

```
$(function() {

    var shrinkHeight = 20,
        originalHeaderHeight = $('header').outerHeight(),
        originalAsidePaddingTop = parseInt($('aside').css('padding-top').slice(0, -2), 10);

    $('body').scroll(function() {

        var distanceScrolled = $(this).scrollTop();

        if(distanceScrolled > 1) {

            $('header').stop().animate({
                height: (originalHeaderHeight - shrinkHeight) + 'px'
            }, {duration: 200, queue: false});

            $('aside').stop().animate({
                paddingTop: (originalAsidePaddingTop - shrinkHeight) + 'px'
            }, {duration: 200, queue: false});

        }
        else {

            $('header').stop().animate({
                height: originalHeaderHeight + 'px'
            }, {duration: 200, queue: false});

            $('aside').stop().animate({
                paddingTop: originalAsidePaddingTop + 'px'
            }, {duration: 200, queue: false});

        }

    });

});
```